# How to do SQL recursive logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have this sample dataset like this ;

| acctid | payseq | totalamount | acctnum | expectprice | payorder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aac1 | 99 | 1000.00 | 1111aa | 800.00 | 1 |
| aac1 | 99 | 1000.00 | 1111bb | 800.00 | 2 |
| aac1 | 99 | 1000.00 | 1111cc | 800.00 | 3 |
| aac1 | 99 | 1000.00 | 1111dd | 1200.00 | 4 |
| aac1 | 100 | 2000.00 | 1111aa | 800.00 | 1 |
| aac1 | 100 | 2000.00 | 1111bb | 800.00 | 2 |
| aac1 | 100 | 2000.00 | 1111cc | 800.00 | 3 |
| aac1 | 100 | 2000.00 | 1111dd | 1200.00 | 4 |

I want a Paid amount column where the total amount is distributed between acctnum for that acctid, payseq combination; the final result should look like this;

| acctid | payseq | totalamount | acctnum | expectprice | payorder | paidamount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aac1 | 99 | 1000.00 | 1111aa | 800.00 | 1 | 800.00 |
| aac1 | 99 | 1000.00 | 1111bb | 800.00 | 2 | 200.00 |
| aac1 | 99 | 1000.00 | 1111cc | 800.00 | 3 |  |
| aac1 | 99 | 1000.00 | 1111dd | 1200.00 | 4 |  |
| aac1 | 100 | 2000.00 | 1111aa | 800.00 | 1 |  |
| aac1 | 100 | 2000.00 | 1111bb | 800.00 | 2 | 600.00 |
| aac1 | 100 | 2000.00 | 1111cc | 800.00 | 3 | 800.00 |
| aac1 | 100 | 2000.00 | 1111dd | 1200.00 | 4 | 600.00 |

For the first payseq 99 - we distribute the total amount 1000 between the first 2 acctnumns (1111aa & 1111bb) based on the expectprice on each acctnum.
For the second payseq 100 - we need to start the distribution from where the first one left, i.e second acctnum had 600 remaining so distribution of total amount of 2000 should be distributed among acctnums (1111bb, 1111cc & 1111dd).
Like wise if there are more payseq's.

I tried using something like

```
totalamount - sum(ifnull(ExpectPrice,0.0)) 
over(partition by acctId, payseq order by payorder asc rows between unbounded preceding and 0 preceding) as PaidAmount
```

but this always starts distribution from first acctnum.

Can anyone help me build a SQL query using recursive CTE or otherwise to accomplish this logic?;

PS: I do not want to write it as stored procedure. I need this in SQL query only.

Have tried writing case statements etc but nothing seems to help!

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text. You need to show 1) sample data 2) required resultset 3) the sql you’ve managed to write so far

Comment: And a tag for the dbms used. SQL syntax differences exist.

Comment: NickW, this was my first post hence bit struggling. I have given the dataset and resultset in the text. Hope this helps, thanks!.

Comment: btw: **case expression** is the correct term for *case when else end* that evaluates to an expression. (Oracle's plsql has a case statement for branching of procedural code, this isn't available in SQL itself.)

Comment: Hmmm... Two dimensional cummulative sum/allocation logic. Now that *is* a challenge.

Comment: I think we need some constraints on the source data to properly work this. (1) WIll a given `acctid` and `payseq` always have the same `totalamount` value? (2) Will a given `acctid` and `payseq` always have the same set of associated `acctnum` values? (3) Will a given `acctnum` always have the same set of associated `expectprice` and `payorder` values? To partially restate the latter, will the `acctnum/payorder` sequence always the same for every `acctid` and `payseq` combination?

Comment: If all of the conditions in the prior question hold true, we appear to be starting with a `CROSS JOIN` of `{acctid, payseq, totalamount}` and `{acctnum, expectprice, payorder}`.  If not, we may be dealing with a many-to-many junction between `{acctid, payseq, totalamount}` and `{acctnum, expectprice}`  defined by  `{acctid, acctnum, payorder}`. The latter would be a much more complicated problem. (It would really help to know the original structure, instead of the single-table flattened version.

Comment: For anyone else looking at this, here is a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/L09T14Cw) with data and a non-working solution.

Comment: @TN yes the dataset is actually a join of 2 datasets; dataset 1 {acctid, payseq and totalamount} and dataset 2 {acctnum,expectprice}

Comment: @Vikraman - That is good, because the first thing I did in my posted solution was to separate out that data into the two original data sets.

Answer (score 0):

This was tricky. In the following discussion, I am going to use the terms "payout" and "payout amount" to refer to the `{acctid, payseq, totalamount}` data and "account" and "expected amount" to refer to the `{acctnum, expectprice, payorder}` data. "Allocated amount" is the calculated result.

For a single payout, the allocated amount from each account can be calculated by first reducing the payout amount by the maximum amount that might have been allocated from accounts with an earlier `payorder`. That adjustment is just the running sum up to the immediately prior row.  That adjusted value is then clamped to the range `[0, expectprice]` of the current row.  If it was negative, we had nothing left to allocate. If it exceeded `expectprice`, we will allocate the full `expectprice` amount and will still have some leftover portion to allocate later.

The problem with this is that this only works for a single payout. If we attempt this for multiple payouts, the numbers reset each time, and we keep allocating the same amounts from the same accounts, not adjusting for already allocated or depleted accounts.

The fix for this was tricky. We need to start out by adjusting the payout amount so that it includes all prior payout amounts. Effectively the current running sum of payout amounts. Now we apply the previously discussed allocation algorithm to the current *adjusted* payout. This will force the allocations to advance past the prior high water mark and allocate *new money* from remaining account funds.

This is good, but we still have a problem. The current allocations also reallocate all previously allocated account funds. How do we fix that?  The answer turns out to be surprisingly simple (well maybe) - we just perform the same allocation calculations for the prior cumulative payout sum and subtract those results from the current calculations.  This will leave just the current allocations with no overlap.

The resulting code is:

```
WITH CTE_Payout AS (
    SELECT *,
        SUM(totalamount) OVER(ORDER BY acctid, payseq) AS CummulativeTotalAmount,
        ISNULL(SUM(totalamount) OVER(
            ORDER BY acctid, payseq
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
            ), 0) AS PriorCummulativeTotalAmount
    FROM Payout P
),
CTE_Acct AS (
    SELECT *,
        ISNULL(SUM(expectprice) OVER(
            ORDER BY payorder
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
            ), 0) AS PriorCummulativeExpectedPrice
    FROM Account A
)
SELECT
    P.acctid, P.payseq, P.totalamount,
    A.acctnum, A.expectprice, A.payorder,
    LEAST(GREATEST(
            P.CummulativeTotalAmount - A.PriorCummulativeExpectedPrice,
        0), A.expectprice)
        - LEAST(GREATEST(
            P.PriorCummulativeTotalAmount - A.PriorCummulativeExpectedPrice,
        0), A.expectprice)
        AS paidamount,
    -- The following just show the working calculations
    P.CummulativeTotalAmount,
    LEAST(GREATEST(
            P.CummulativeTotalAmount - A.PriorCummulativeExpectedPrice,
        0), A.expectprice)
        AS CurrentCummulativeAllocation,
    P.PriorCummulativeTotalAmount,
    LEAST(GREATEST(
            P.PriorCummulativeTotalAmount - A.PriorCummulativeExpectedPrice,
        0), A.expectprice)
        AS PriorCummulativeAllocation
FROM CTE_Payout P
CROSS APPLY CTE_Acct A
ORDER BY acctid, payseq, payorder
```

Results (with intermediate calculations):

| acctid | payseq | totalamount | acctnum | expectprice | payorder | paidamount | Cummulative Total Amount | Cummulative Allocation | Prior Cummulative Total Amount | Prior Cummulative Allocation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aac1 | 99 | 1000.00 | 1111aa | 800.00 | 1 | 800.00 | 1000.00 | 800.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| aac1 | 99 | 1000.00 | 1111bb | 800.00 | 2 | 200.00 | 1000.00 | 200.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| aac1 | 99 | 1000.00 | 1111cc | 800.00 | 3 | 0.00 | 1000.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| aac1 | 99 | 1000.00 | 1111dd | 1200.00 | 4 | 0.00 | 1000.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| aac1 | 100 | 2000.00 | 1111aa | 800.00 | 1 | 0.00 | 3000.00 | 800.00 | 1000.00 | 800.00 |
| aac1 | 100 | 2000.00 | 1111bb | 800.00 | 2 | 600.00 | 3000.00 | 800.00 | 1000.00 | 200.00 |
| aac1 | 100 | 2000.00 | 1111cc | 800.00 | 3 | 800.00 | 3000.00 | 800.00 | 1000.00 | 0.00 |
| aac1 | 100 | 2000.00 | 1111dd | 1200.00 | 4 | 600.00 | 3000.00 | 600.00 | 1000.00 | 0.00 |

Note that `paidamount = CummulativeAllocation - PriorCummulativeAllocation`.

It wouldn't take much to wrap the final select above into a subquery or another CTE and apply a filter `WHERE paidamount <> 0` to eliminate unnecessary results.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n-EmAk1R) for a demo.

Comment: I've updated this answer to now work with two separate source data tables.

Comment: this is awesome! Appreciate your quick response and solution. However I was looking for something that can do it recursively. The number of payseq for acctid can be more than 2. Once again thanks a ton for this. This is definitely useful.

Comment: I ran a test with after injecting a couple more payouts, and the results seems to be as expected. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GP3R4XNN). One think came to mind that I think you should check, is the payout ordering. My posted logic ordered the payouts with `ORDER BY acctid, payseq`, but you might prefer to use `ORDER BY payseq, acctid`.

Comment: Hey @TN, thanks for the solution; the solution did work on the other data set but there is another scenario where the result seems to be in correct. Here is the new dataset;        
INSERT Payout
VALUES
    ('aac2',  27, 3000.00),
    ('aac2',  28, 6000.00)-- Added

INSERT Account
VALUES
    ('2222aa',  3000.00, 1),
    ('2222bb',  3000.00, 2)
For the second payseq = 28 , the paid amount seems to be not equal to the total amount of 6000.

Comment: @Vikraman - The posted code assumes a distinct payorder values, but the newly inserted Account rows duplicate payorder values 1 and 2. Try changing these to 5 and 6 and retry. Alternately, you can modify the posted code to ensure an unambiguous ordering by changing `ORDER BY payorder` to `ORDER BY payorder, acctnum` anywhere it appears.

Comment: Hey @TN, I am not sure I understand, this is a completely new dataset - new set of acctid and new set of acctnum.

Comment: @Vikraman - I was confused by the `-- Added` in your earlier post, but I guess that was just a cut& paste issue. As I understand your new data, you are attempting to pay out a total of 9000 (3000+6000), but your accounts only have 6000 (3000+3000) available. As a result, both accounts are depleted and the last payout is only partially paid. If you had provided another account, say `('2222cc', 9999.00, 3)`, the remaining payout amount would have been paid out of that.

Comment: Hi @TN..Actually the payout needs to be done on the individual payseq however the amounts on the individual acctnum needs to be carried over across the payseq. So for first payseq the total amount is 3000 hence only one acctnum will be applicable however for second payseq even though there is no amount carried over on first acctnum the amount of 3000 needs to be applied to both acctnums so as to distribute the amount of 6000.

Comment: @Vikraman - I am not sure what you mean by "carried over across the payseq". In your original question you stated "we need to start the distribution from where the first one left". Your requirements appear to be changing and conflicting. Consider your original example. After processing payouts 99 and 100, accounts 1, 2 and 3 are depleted, but 4 still has 600 remaining. If you were to another payout of 3000, what would be your expected results? I don't see how you could allocate more than the remaining 600. I suggest you post a fiddle showing where your expectations differ from the actual.

Comment: @Vikraman - Were you able to resolve your issues?